# Asp.net mvc authentication with entity framework on windows Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, authentication, azure

is it possible to make asp.net mvc web portal with authorization on windows azure. I want to use Entity framework to access database. Is it possible and if it is, how can I do it?

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely it can be done with MVC, EF and Azure. You need to

1. Create ASP.Net membership provider tables in SQL Azure. See [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jnak/archive/2009/11/24/asp-net-provider-scripts-for-sql-azure.aspx)
2. Get EF membership provider implementation from [here](http://efmembership.codeplex.com/)
3. Have a look at the ASP.Net MVC membership starter kit [here](http://mvcmembership.codeplex.com/) to see how it provides pre build component to to authentication and authorization.

I would recommend not to create any of your own infrastructure for authentication or authorization but leverage the ASP.Net buildin infrastructure